# Rails forms using collection_radio_buttons on array instead of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, collections, radio-button

Rails has a form helper `f.collection_radio_buttons` which operates very similar to the `f.collection_select` form helper.

However, `f.colleciton_radio_buttons` only works on collections of objects and doesn't work with a simple array.

As an example, I can have:

```
<%= f.select :attribute, ["First", "Second"] %>
```

But there isn't any:

```
<%= f.radio_buttons :attribute, ["First", "Second"] %>
```

So to make `f.collection_radio_buttons` work with a simple array I have to do:

```
<%= f.collection_radio _buttons :attribute, ["First", "Second"], :to_s, :to_s %>
```

This "works" but it seems very hacky.  Is there a cleaner way to reference the value of an array instead of calling `.to_s` on it?

Comment: Try `:itself`. It just returns itself :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is an old post but if it is helpful for somebody else then here it is. Now in 2019, I'm working with **Rails 5** application and I have a form where I had to show two radio buttons for a given attribute.

**I a helper method I have:**

```rb
def get_company_segments
    company = current_user.branch.company
    [
        [company.various_segment_fee, 'various', 'Varios'],
        [company.metal_segment_fee, 'metal', 'Metal']
    ]
end

Output:
#=> [["12.6", "various", "Varios"], ["10", "metal", "Metal"]]
```

**Then in my form view I have something like:**

```
<%= form.collection_radio_buttons(:segment, get_company_segments, :second, :last) do |segment| %>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <%= segment.radio_button(class: 'form-check-input', id: "agreement_segment_#{segment.object.second}" %>
        <%= segment.label(class: 'form-check-label', for: "agreement_segment_#{segment.object.second}") %>
    </div>
<%- end %>
```

**And it renders something like this:**

[image]

**And the HTML looks like this:**

```html
<div class="form-check custom-radio form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" id="agreement_segment_various" data-fee="12.6" type="radio" value="various" name="agreement[segment]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="agreement_segment_various">Varios</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check custom-radio form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" id="agreement_segment_metal" data-fee="10" type="radio" value="metal" name="agreement[segment]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="agreement_segment_metal">Metal</label>
</div>
```

I hope it could be a good reference for anyone else.